# Is it possible to unzip a nsbundle with zipzap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unzip, nsbundle, zipzap

I was looking in Cocoapods the most popular unzipper and zipzap won... but, can zipzap uncompress a nsbundle?

My zip file is called "content.bundle.zip" and when I try to uncompress it, the entries filenames are:

```
content.bundle/file-01.jpg
content.bundle/file-02.jpg
content.bundle/file-03.jpg
...
```

Looks like zipzap cannot recognize content.bundle as a folder

Comment: afaik that is documented together with some code showing how to handle.. but i might be wrong.

Comment: Solved. I compressed the zip using a PC. Now compressing with a Mac, it works perfectly! https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap/issues/81